# iOS - navigation bar displayed when UISearchController is active

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I programatically created a UISearchController and added it to my UIView A. I also have a UITableView in the same UIView. I use  UISearchController to search through my UITableView.  When you click on a cell, UIView B gets pushed. Both UIView A and UIView B have UINavigationBar set to HIDDEN. 
When I simply click on a UITableViewCell WITHOUT searching, everything happens perfectly, and UIView B is displayed without UINavigationBar.

But when I am searching using the UISearchController and I click on a UITableViewCell, the UINavigationBar is displayed on UIView B, even though I set it to hidden in the viewDidAppear method.

Here is my code:

```
BarsSearchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
BarsSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
BarsSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
BarsSearchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
BarsSearchController.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
BarsSearchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
[searchBarView addSubview:BarsSearchController.searchBar];
[searchBarView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:BarsSearchController.searchBar
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:searchBarView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0]];

[searchBarView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:BarsSearchController.searchBar
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:searchBarView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0]];

[searchBarView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:BarsSearchController.searchBar
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:searchBarView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0]];

[searchBarView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:BarsSearchController.searchBar
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:searchBarView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0]];
[searchBarView layoutIfNeeded];
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
[BarsSearchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: BarsSearchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = YES;

Answer (score 0):

```
BarsSearchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = YES;
```

Comment: Actually, sorry, this doesn't work...the default value is already YES, and the navigation bar is still displayed. Other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, to fix it, I hide back button and background in viewDidLoad :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    [[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
    [[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setTranslucent:YES];
}
```

and I hide navigationBar in viewDidAppear :

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}
```